# two styles change within one if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web design . I am trying to achieve this code but only one style works Please help me correct this code. How am I supposed to achieve these two styles?

```
// Get the sign_up model winow
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// Get the contents from the container 
var content = document.getElementById('container');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close the model and set the container contents blur to "0"
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        content.style.filter = "blur(0)";
    }
}
```

Comment: if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            content.style.filter="blur(0)";
        }
are these lines correct?
i am talking about the syntax

Comment: Where  is the html and the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 100% works. I believe, your only problem is, that `blur(0)` actually removes your blur (is this what you really want to achieve?).

I tried it and it works ... look also into DOM on console. You will see, that the style is applied propertly.

In my fiddle, I added positive value to `blur()` to actually see the effect

https://jsfiddle.net/9tqfcyf6/